# What limits the options in a Bulk Operations Menu (beyond their initial settings) regarding rule components?

Tags: 7, users, views

I created a View Bulk Operation (VBO) that should allow an admin user to change the author of several nodes at once.  Everything works fine when I am logged in as the root user.  However, when I am logged in as a different kind of admin user, the VBO drop down menu is empty.  I am assuming that there is a setting somewhere that is preventing the menu item(s) from appearing in the drop down list.  What could be causing this to happen?  I checked my permissions, but there did not seem to be a VBO related permission for the specific drop down option that I have enabled for this.

My setup uses a flag to target a user and a [rules link](https://drupal.org/project/rules_link) to target an entity.  the rules link triggers a 'rule component rule' which changes the author of the target node.  I have a view table that renders this rule link as a column and also has a VBO column that can trigger the rule link for multiple columns.

Edit: I added a new test VBO action which calls a rule component rule (that only sets a Drupal message.)  This option does not appear for the admin users either.

Edit: the admin user role has full read and write permissions for the content type.

Edit: After enabling all VBO permissions for everyone, the option is still not available.

Edit: I noticed that the Rules Link is not shown in the view for the other admin role.

Edit: After enabling the permissions for all Rule Links, the link is displayed, but still not the VBO option.

Edit: I was able to add generic VBO operations (which could be seen by the admin roles.)  This problem only seems to effect VBO operations that are created by rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are adding operations using **Rules Component** then you have to set the permission.

Edit your rule component and under the settings there will be **Configure access for using this component with a permission.**, set your permission here.

Comment: I see, that's the check box at the very bottom of the settings area.  It works fine after setting that permission.  I wonder why this permission section exists outside of the permissions page.  What is this section intended to be used for?